# Nested Invoke-Command results in PSSessionStateBroken, PSRemotingTransportException

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have three boxes: A, B, C.
I'm trying to invoke a command on C from A without prompting for credentials.

I can invoke command successfully
a) on B from A 
b) on C from B 
but cannot invoke
c) on C from A with nested Invoke-Command

I think I can make a workaround with calling A and C from B.
But it's still bothering me why it doesn't work this way. All the three boxes seem to be configured properly.
I can't even figure out if it's an authentication or network issue.

Any help please?

The error is:

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message: 
WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using 
Negotiate authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. 
It may already have been terminated.
(...)
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
+ PSComputerName        : [IP]
```

Details:
Preparing stored password:

```
$key = ([KEY])
Read-Host -AsSecureString| ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key| Out-File [PATH]
```

Invocation A > B

```
$key = ([KEY])
$pw = Get-Content "[PATH1]"| ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("[USER1]", $pw)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [B] -Credential $cred { dir c:\ }
```

This gets me proper result (directory listing).

Invocation B > C (the same, except for path, user, etc.)

```
$k = ([KEY])
$p = Get-Content "[PATH2]"| ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $k
$c = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("[USER2]", $p)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [C] -Credential $c { dir c:\ }
```

This gets me proper result (directory listing).

Now, combined invocation A > C:

```
$key = ([KEY])
$pw = Get-Content "[PATH1]"| ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("[USER1]", $pw)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [B] -Credential $cred { $k = ([KEY]); $p = Get-Content "[PATH2]"| ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $k; $c = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("[USER2]", $p); Invoke-Command -ComputerName [C] -Credential $c { dir c:\ } }
```

yields the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Invoke-Command` parameter `-Authentication Credssp`.  This is a typical solution for double-hop credential problems.